# Подключение freeglut через cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Пытаюсь подключить freeglut через cmake, использую компилятор Visual studio

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

file(GLOB cpps ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sources/*.cpp)
file(GLOB hpps ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sources/*.hpp)

#GLUT
set(GLUT_ROOT C:/Libraries/freeglut) #не находит без этого
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
if(GLUT_FOUND)
    message("GLUT is found here:")
    message("\tInclude dir ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("\tLibraries   ${GLUT_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if(OpenGL_FOUND)
    message("OpenGL is found here:")
    message("\tInclude dir ${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message("\tLibraries   ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${hpps} ${cpps})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Конфигурация проходит успешно, но при запуске программа получаю такую ошибку:
[image: Информаци об ошибке]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: скопировать dll  к бинарнику?

Comment: Хотел именно указать где взять ее, а не копировать. Но в идеале настроить статическую линковку.